# COMMITTING_TOP_LEVEL_VALUES_NOT_SUPPORTED: Javers exception, springboot and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javers, code-auditing

I am using javers in my spring boot with Mongodb, when updating or deleting I get the error COMMITTING_TOP_LEVEL_VALUES_NOT_SUPPORTED:Committing top-level ValueTypes like 'String' is not supported. You can commit only Entity or ValueObject instance.

this is my document class for mongodb

```
@Document("admin_users")
public class Admin_users {

@Id
private ObjectId _id;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String userName;

private String password;
@CreatedDate
private Date dateCreated;
@LastModifiedDate
private Date dateModified;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String emailAddress;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@Version
private Long version;
```

this is my repository

```
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
@Repository
public interface AdminUsersRepository extends MongoRepository<Admin_users,String>, 
CustomAdminUsersRepository {

boolean existsByEmailAddress(String email);


}
```

and this is my service

```
@Service
public class AdminUsersServiceImpl implements AdminUsersService {

@Autowired
AdminUsersRepository adminUsersRepository;


@JaversAuditable
@Override
public Admin_users updateAdminUser(Admin_users payload, String id) {
    if(!adminUsersRepository.existsById(id)){
        throw new InvalidException("Record Not Found");
    }

    adminUsersRepository.save(payload);
    return null;


}
```

and this is the stacktrace

```
org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: COMMITTING_TOP_LEVEL_VALUES_NOT_SUPPORTED: Committing top-level ValueTypes like 'String' is not supported. You can commit only Entity or ValueObject instance.
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.assertJaversTypeNotValueTypeOrPrimitiveType(JaversCore.java:97) ~[javers-core-5.9.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:81) ~[javers-core-5.9.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversCommitAdvice.commitObject(JaversCommitAdvice.java:81) ~[javers-spring-5.9.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversCommitAdvice.commitSaveMethodArguments(JaversCommitAdvice.java:54) ~[javers-spring-5.9.1.jar:na]
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableAspect.commitAdvice(JaversAuditableAspect.java:45) ~[javers-spring-5.9.1.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:626) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.afterReturning(AspectJAfterReturningAdvice.java:66) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.inventa.InventaService.Service.AdminUsersServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d3b2d1b.updateAdminUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.inventa.InventaService.Controller.AdminUsersController.updateAdminUser(AdminUsersController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.inventa.InventaService.Security.JwtAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthorizationFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
```

Can you please let me know what is the problem, I am stuck here and cannot figure out the way. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Javers is a kind of object database. The problem is that you are not committing objects but primitives - `String`. How do you want to track changes on a detached `String`? How do you want to load this `String` from a repository? It just not make any sense.

Comment: What should be the work around for this? I need to use this on my delete service as well which has String id argument. How do I implement Javers in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Javers only accepts objects. You can only save objects into Javers. You don't need the annotation @JaversAuditable for updateAdminUser method.
@JaversSpringDataAuditable in your repository should handle the adminUsersRepository.save() method for you.

Additionally, adminUsersRepository.existsById method should not be used with @JaversAuditable

```
@Autowired
Javers javers;

@Override
public Admin_users updateAdminUser(Admin_users payload, String id) {
    if(!adminUsersRepository.existsById(id)){
        throw new InvalidException("Record Not Found");
    }

    adminUsersRepository.save(payload);
    return null;


}
```

The delete service should also follow the same logic. You only delete data using the adminUsersRepository.delete method. No need for annotations in the service. @JaversSpringDataAuditable should handle it for you.